# Congratulations, You Won "Enthusiast"....Err, Woot

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

I signed into SO today to find the magical orange-overseer alerting me that I've won a new badge called "Enthusiast." I was pretty excited, and rushed to my profile to check it out - well, there's "Woot," which is new for me. But I wasn't able to find "Enthusiast." Is this a mix-up with names, since you are considered an "enthusiast" if you are awarded "woot"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Woot (woot.com) is sponsoring the enthusiast badge for the time being, hence the rename. I recommend that you read the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/) for more details.

Comment: I knew that Woot! was responsible for a new badge, but plastering a big "Woot" label on it and still calling it "Enthusiast" is confusing. Oh well, thanks for the clarity.

Comment: I agree.  This just happened to me, and I was extremely confused...

Answer (score 4):

Ah... Was about to post a question about Enthusiast badge. It's a WOOT!

[image: Woot!???]

Comment: +1 for the freeness of that circle.

Comment: -1 for using shadows

Comment: DXXn! I forgot to turn off the shadow effect.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, next up...the Fanatic badge!

Comment: Apparently only 70 days to go :) Well, that is assuming my enthusiast-days rollover into my fanatic-days.

Comment: Is there a way we can find out how many days in a row we've visited?  At one time, a moderator told me that I started a fresh run on April 9th, so I have tried very hard to make sure to log in everyday since, but I'm not sure if this worked out... Moderator help?  SU <-

Comment: Go to your profile page and it should say visited for x days y consecutive. If you click on that you'll see a calendar showing exactly which days.