# Is the Enthusiast badge still undead?

Tags: support, badges

In the "You've earned" messages "Enthusiast" has not been
renamed to "woot!". Is this a bug?

[alt text http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/MSO/EnthusiastBagde_2009-09-15.png](http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/MSO/EnthusiastBagde_2009-09-15.png)

[alt text http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/MSO/Bagdes_2009-09-15.png](http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/MSO/Bagdes_2009-09-15.png)

Summary:

In a Stack Overflow blog entry,
"[Enthusiast and Fanatic Badges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/)", the renaming was announced:
"For the period of sponsorship, we’ve renamed this the woot!
badge. (It’ll revert to Enthusiast once that period is
over.)"

Here is a [similiar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2423) - but I report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a bug. It's still the Enthusiast badge. It's just that the image of the badge itself has been sponsored by the woot!

They may have the face, but they haven't got the bones.

Comment: If not a bug I still find it confusing.

Comment: That it can be.

Comment: Anything that confuses a user is a bug. Either in the UI or in the user.

Comment: Just earned this badge myself recently. Took a few minutes of wondering where the badge was, until I noticed I was WOOTed...

Answer (score 2):

Sponsorship period runs through Dec 31st 2009